# What is BLOB filetype?

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, plupload

I've got upload.php file with these file types allowed:

```
$allowedExtensions = array("mp3","mp4","jpg","jpeg","gif","png");
```

It performs upload correctly but when uploaded file is larger than 5mb (chunk size is set to 5mb) then it stops working unless I extend my array with BLOB (Javascript console returned this error as response from upload.php - that's how I know what was the problem):

```
$allowedExtensions = array("mp3","mp4","jpg","jpeg","gif","png","blob");
```

Can anyone explain me what that BLOB is? It's some kind of upload PART/CHUNK stored on server? Are there any other surprises I should include in `allowedExtensions`?

My upload.php is the one from Plupload.com: https://github.com/downloads/moxiecode/plupload/plupload_1_5_4.zip (unzip, go to /examples/ and open upload.php). I only extended it by adding this:

```
foreach($_FILES as $file){
    if($file['tmp_name'] > ''){
        if(!in_array(end(explode(".", strtolower($file['name']))), $allowedExtensions)){
            die($file['name'].' is not an allowed file type!');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object

Comment: Without knowing how `allowedExtensions` gets used it's hard to say

Comment: @ExplosionPills Wait a second... I will post link.

Answer (score 1):

BLOB = Binary Large OBject. Its a database field type for storing binary data.

Without starting a war, IMHO pictures do not belong in a database. Store them on disk and keep a reference to them in a database table.

Comment: Thanks! Please check my upload.php and `allowedExtensions` check. I think I store everything on server and it does not even connect to database. Yet, I must add it to `allowedExtensions` to enable chunking. I fixed it but I just need a little bit more explanation on why is that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_FILES as $file){
    if(isset($file['tmp_name']) &&  $file['tmp_name'] != ''){ <--- HERE IS THE CHANGE
        if(!in_array(end(explode(".", strtolower($file['name']))), $allowedExtensions)){
            die($file['name'].' is not an allowed file type!');
        }
    }
}
```

I modified your loop to help avoid warnings.